# Group timestamped records by consecutive repeating flag

Tags: sql, hive

I have a dataset with the following columns:

```
DriverId  DateStamp        IsDriving  WasDriving DistanceSincePrev SecondsSincePrev
1         11/10/2018 08:00 0          0          0                 12
1         11/10/2018 08:01 1          0          10                60
1         11/10/2018 08:01 1          1          100               54
1         11/10/2018 08:02 1          1          14                32
1         11/10/2018 08:03 1          1          33                60
1         11/10/2018 08:04 0          1          10                59
1         11/10/2018 08:04 0          0          0                 60
1         11/10/2018 08:05 1          0          0                 60
1         11/10/2018 08:06 1          1          500               43
1         11/10/2018 08:06 0          1          300               32
1         11/10/2018 08:07 0          0          0                 60
1         11/10/2018 08:08 0          0          0                 12
1         11/10/2018 08:09 0          0          10                60
1         11/10/2018 08:10 0          0          100               54
1         11/10/2018 08:11 0          0          14                32
1         11/10/2018 08:12 0          0          33                60
1         11/10/2018 08:13 0          0          10                59
1         11/10/2018 08:14 0          0          0                 60
1         11/10/2018 08:15 1          0          0                 60
1         11/10/2018 08:16 1          1          500               43
1         11/10/2018 08:16 1          1          300               32
1         11/10/2018 08:17 1          1          0                 60
1         11/10/2018 08:18 1          1          500               43
1         11/10/2018 08:19 1          1          300               32
1         11/10/2018 08:19 1          1          0                 60
1         11/10/2018 08:20 1          1          500               43
1         11/10/2018 08:21 1          1          300               32
1         11/10/2018 08:22 1          1          0                 60
1         11/10/2018 08:23 1          1          500               43
1         11/10/2018 08:24 1          1          300               32
1         11/10/2018 08:24 0          1          0                 60
1         11/10/2018 08:25 0          0          0                 60
```

As you can see, those are timestamps of a person's driving. I'd like to group those timestamps into RIDES, and by that I mean sections where the person is driving without turning the engine off. In this dataset, I can use the 'IsDriving' and 'WasDriving' columns to do that. But I am having problems with writing the query.

I have 2 ideas on how the algorithm might work

1) More ideal, probably more difficult: the query would detect the records where IsDriving is 1 and WasDriving is 0 and count that as the beginning of the ride. Then it would detect the record where IsDriving is 0 and WasDriving is 1 and it would end the ride there.

2) Somewhat of a heuristic, but it would be gould enough: the query would simply aggregate records where both IsDriving and WasDriving is set to 1 consecutively and count that as a single ride.

Unfortunately, I can't get my head around putting that algotithm into SQL.

Ideally, my output would look like that:

```
DriverId StartOfRide       DistanceOfRide  LengthOfRide
1        11/10/2018 08:00  1400            221
1        11/10/2018 08:30  5900            329
1        11/10/2018 12:00  21400           3600
```

Comment: Your query isnt clear so as to what you are actually trying to achieve in the output. If you could share more input data maybe itll clear more

Comment: Sorry. Basically, the premise is this: There are some records that have the 'IsDriving' flag set to 1 consecutively. That means that for as long as the 'IsDriving' flag is set, the driver was driving without turning off the engine. Then he finished his ride, and for some time the 'IsDriving' flag is set back to 0. I would like to aggregate those times where the 'IsDriving' flag is set to 1 for longer (consecutive) periods of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign groups and then aggregate.  In this case, you can define a group as the number of `0` values in `IsDriving` up to each record.  Then aggregate:

```
select driverid, min(datestamp) as startofride,
       sum(distance) as distance,
       sum(seconds) as seconds
from (select t.*,
             sum(1 - isdriving) over (partition by driverid order by datestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by driverid, grp
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do, remove/add columns you don't/do need:

```
create table #tmp (DriverId int , DateStamp datetime, IsDriving int , WasDriving int, DistanceSincePrev float, SecondsSincePrev float)

insert into #tmp values 
(1,        ' 11/10/2018 08:00', 0  ,        0     ,     0      ,           12),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:01', 1 ,         0  ,        10  ,              60),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:01' ,1 ,         1  ,        100 ,              54),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:02' ,1 ,         1   ,       14  ,              32),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:03' ,1 ,         1    ,      33,                60),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:04' ,0 ,         1     ,     10  ,              59),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:04' ,0 ,         0      ,    0   ,              60),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:05' ,1 ,         0    ,      0   ,              60),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:06' ,1 ,         1      ,    500  ,             43),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:06' ,0 ,         1     ,     300  ,             32),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:07' ,0 ,         0     ,     0    ,             60),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:08' ,0 ,         0     ,     0   ,              12),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:09' ,0 ,         0     ,     10  ,              60),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:10' ,0 ,         0     ,     100,               54),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:11' ,0 ,         0     ,     14 ,               32),
(1,        ' 11/10/2018 08:12' ,0 ,         0     ,     33  ,              60),
(1,         '11/10/2018 08:13' ,0 ,         0     ,     10  ,              59)





select * from 

(
select DateStamp as RideStart,DriverID, Grp,(SUM(DistanceSincePrev) over (partition by grp)) as DistanceofRide,
(SUM(SecondsSincePrev ) over (partition by grp)) as LengthofRide,
ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by driverid,grp order by datestamp) r
from
(
 SELECT
    *,
    Grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY driverID ORDER BY DateStamp) -
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY driverID,IsDriving ORDER BY DateStamp)
  FROM #tmp
) s
) x
where r = 1
```